# Chrome / Chromium always loses session tabs after restart

Tags: arch-linux, chrome

I have been using Chrome / Chromium on ubuntu and arch linux more recently.

Under ubuntu, the tabs weren't lost all the time, it happened infrequently but quite often.

On arch (antergos atm, but also on manjaro), the session is always lost between restarts, on both browsers, and I have to always click the "Restore tabs" button.

Does anyone else experience this? What might be the cause for this? And how can I debug it?

Comment: Have you set chromium to open the previous tabs on startup? It's an option, I don't think it's on by default.

Comment: I did, of course. I don't think you would have the option to restore tabs if this weren't turn on.

Comment: Does it work as expected if you close chromium first, and then restart? What desktop en ironment are you using?

Comment: I always close it properly. It retains sessions if I close and reopen the browser. I use GNOME, but have also seen it happen on Unity (ubuntu) and openbox (manjaro), although on manjaro it happened every 1 out of 5 times. could it have anything to do with the keyring password?